# WebBrowser Control: Is there a good documentation on browsing local files and folders?

Tags: browser, directory, local

I am using the WebBrowser control to browse local files and folders, but the control seems to be designed primarily to browse the Web (as its name implies).

I need to be able to do common tasks, like using the "Up one level" button, or put the control in "File Search" mode, get the active item, etc.

Is there a way to do these things using this control?
Is there a comprehensive documentation somewhere to explain local browsing using the WebBrowser?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [good intro](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html) that should help you get started on this.  Most of the work with this dialog will be done by the browser, you need only to prompt it how to open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing the WebBrowser control with Windows Explorer.

If you want to browse around your local file system, then you need to add an Open File Dialog to the form containing the Web Browser control, then have a button of some kind open that dialog to locate the file to load into the WebBrowser control.

Comment: Actually I need an explorer to be shown inside my app. I need all of its functions, like its context menu, etc.